# Sending a csv file via curl POST to Django REST Framework endpoint

Tags: python, django, curl, django-rest-framework

I have a csv file that I want to send via curl to a Django Rest Framework API View I have developed. The csv file itself contains only `foo,bar` and this is the curl command I'm using:

```
curl URL -H 'Accept: 
application/json' -H 'Referer: http://localhost:5011/ost:5011' -H 
'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 
Safari/537.36' -H 'Authorization: JWT TOKEN  -H 'Content-Type: 
multipart/form-data' -F upload=@testcsv.csv
```

When it hits my API View in Django, and I run

```
request.data.get('file').read()
```

the output is some metadata around the file and not the file contents itself:

```
(Pdb) b'--------------------------001ec735bfc1a929\r\nContent-
Disposition: form-data; name="upload"; 
filename="testcsv.csv"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-
stream\r\n\r\n\r\n--------------------------001ec735bfc1a929--\r\n'
```

How can I access the actual file itself through this method? My APIview is using

```
class FileUploadView(APIView):
     parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
f = request.FILES["filefield_name"]
```